# No Places, Trash, Network, Recent search in Dolphin

Tags: dolphin

I don't know if the questions about Kubuntu are allowed here. I am having a problem with Dolphin. On the left sidebar in Dolphin, there isn't Places, Network, Recent search, Trash etc. I tried to add a trash via 'New Entry' and adding trash:/ but it disappears.

Is there something I can do about this issue?

[image]

Comment: Kubuntu is an official Ubuntu flavor therefore is on-topic.

Comment: Hm, Places is now magically back. Could be related with 0 MB free space in my home partition?!

Comment: It could be related indeed.